# TeamCity XML report processing result

Tags: java, teamcity, checkstyle, findbugs, teamcity-9.0

Is there a way to retrieve TC XML Report Processing result? I mean checkstyle and findbugs errors. I think they should stored on disk, but i didn't find right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report processing results are stored in the database and there is no way to retrieve them via API